# java - pass metod reference to an interface argument?

Tags: java, java-8

I came across this example:

```
package br.com.teste;

class HighTemp {
    private int hTemp;
    HighTemp(int ht) {
        hTemp = ht;
    }
    boolean sameTemp(HighTemp ht2) {
        return hTemp == ht2.hTemp;
    }
}

interface MyFunc152<T> {
    boolean func(T v1, T v2);
}

class InstanceMethWithObjectRefDemo {
    static <T> int counter(T[] vals, MyFunc152<T> f, T v) {
        int count = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < vals.length; i++)
            if (f.func(vals[i], v)) count++;
        return count;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int count;
        HighTemp[] weekDayHighs = { new HighTemp(89), new HighTemp(82), new HighTemp(90), new HighTemp(89) };

        count = counter(weekDayHighs, HighTemp::sameTemp, new HighTemp(89));
        System.out.println(count + " days had a same of 89");
    }
}
```

Why this works? Particularly the part where an method reference is passed to a function with an interface argument.

```
        count = counter(weekDayHighs, HighTemp::sameTemp, new HighTemp(89));
```

Why HighTemp::sameTemp is valid as MyFunc152 ? And why passing HighTemp::sameTemp does not generate a compile error if sameTemp is not static?

Comment: This is using [Functional Interfaces](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html#approach6) and [Method References](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you are passing to your `counter` method a `HighTemp[]`, which means it expects an instance of `MyFunc152<HighTemp>` as the second argument.

Now, `HighTemp::sameTemp` is a method reference to a method with two `HighTemp` arguments (the first of them is implicit - the `HighTemp` instance the method will be called on) and a `boolean` return type. This is an exact match to the `boolean func(HighTemp v1, HighTemp v2)` method of the `MyFunc152<HighTemp>` functional interface.

Inside your `counter` method, when you call the functional interface method with `f.func(vals[i], v)`, it is equivalent to calling `vals[i].sameTemp(v)`.

Instead of passing the method reference `HighTemp::sameTemp`, you could have passed an equivalent lambda expression `(HighTemp t1,HighTemp t2)->t1.sameTemp(t2)` (or simply `(t1,t2)->t1.sameTemp(t2)`).

Comment: so  MyFunc152<T> func(T v1, T v2) gets mapped to (h1, h2) -> h1.sameTemp(h2). Think i got it! Thanks.